# Is there a way to make custom lookup on dialog field on Microsoft Dynamics 365?

Tags: dialog, lookup, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365

I have problems with my dialog field. I have button that opens dialog tab with field. It was supposed to show on that field lookup exact records(i guess i need select there by one field value). Right now i have this code:

```
 DialogField Journal = dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr(JournalId));
```

This dialog line adds a field with all values on that EDT. I have 3 journal types - NEW, UPDATE, DELETE. Right now on that field lookup it shows me all 3 journal types. I want to make custom lookup that shows exact type , example - if i click that button on journal that has type "NEW", then it should show only "NEW" type of journal types on lookup. I heard there is something like dialog.addLookup or something. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You already added your dialog field (in the `dialog()` method). Now add the `dialogRunPost()` method that is executed *after* the form GUI is initialized. At that point you can fetch the underlying `FormStringControl` behind the dialog field. Subscribing to the `FormStringControl.OnLookup` event allows you to override the lookup.

I did not have some journal data available, so I created a similar example with customers. My example dialog (`MyDialog`) takes a source customer (`customerCaller`) and shows a dialog with a custom lookup that only shows customers with the same customer group.

My example is also a standalone, runnable class and is not called from a form. Comments have been added to indicate where this affects the code.

**Full example**

```
public class MyDialog extends Runbase
{
    // fields
    protected Args args;
    protected CustTable customerCaller;
    protected DialogField dfCustomerId;

    // construct
    public static MyDialog newArgs(Args _args)
    {
        MyDialog ret = new MyDialog();
        
        ret.args = _args;

        return ret;
    }

    // initialize
    public boolean init()
    {
        boolean ret = super();

        // validate and fetch caller
        if (args.record() && args.record().TableId == tableNum(CustTable))
      //if (args.caller() && args.caller().dataset() == tableNum(CustTable)) --> when called from form
        {
            customerCaller = args.record();
          //customerCaller = args.caller().record();
        }
        else
        {
            throw error(Error::missingRecord('My Dialog'));
        }
    
        return ret;
    }

    // build dialog
    public Object dialog()
    {
        Dialog ret = super();

        // optional reference to visualize the input
        ret.addText('Caller customer group = ' + customerCaller.CustGroup);

        // add field
        dfCustomerId = ret.addField(extendedTypeStr(CustAccount)); // default lookup = all CustTable.AccountNum values
    
        return ret;
    }

    public void dialogPostRun(DialogRunbase dialog)
    {
        super(dialog);

        // subscribe to lookup event
        FormStringControl fscCustomerId = dfCustomerId.control();
        fscCustomerId .OnLookup += eventhandler(this.customerId_OnLookup);
    }

    // custom lookup for customer id
    protected void customerId_OnLookup(FormControl _sender, FormControlEventArgs _e)
    {
        // cancel default
        FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs eventArgs = _e;
        eventArgs.CancelSuperCall();
 
        // define lookup query (list all customers with same customer group as input customer)
        Query query = new Query();
        QueryBuildDataSource qbds = SysQuery::findOrCreateDataSource(query, tableNum(CustTable));
        SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldNum(CustTable, CustGroup)).value(SysQuery::value(customerCaller.CustGroup));

        // do lookup
        SysTableLookup lookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(CustTable), _sender);
        lookup.parmQuery(query);
        lookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum), true);
        lookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(CustTable, CustGroup));
        lookup.performFormLookup();
    }

    // run dialog
    public static void main(Args _args)
    {
        // I am running this dialog directly (not from a form), generating some random input
        CustTable customer;
        select firstonly customer where customer.CustGroup != '';
        _args.record(customer);
        // end of random input

        MyDialog md = MyDialog::newArgs(_args);
        md.init();

        if (md.prompt())
        {
            md.run();
        }
    }

}
```

**Result**

[image: example output]